# Read file as list of tuples and display in answer format

Tags: python, tuples

I have to read a text file (notepad txt) which is in the format of:

Why are manhole covers round in shape?

The cover cannot fall through if it is circular._Circular covers do not need to be precisely aligned._A round cover is easy to move and roll._Human beings have a roughly circular cross section._All of the above.

5

What is the result of dividing 3 by 4?

1.33333...._0.75._12._7._7._0.7777777777777

2

In the series 1,2,3,4,5,...100, how many of these numbers have the digit 7 in them?

9._10._19._20._11

3

The answers are separated by (._) and the answer is the number that follows the question as it coresponds to the answer choices.

I want to have each set of questions stored as a tuple in a list. And I want to display on screen in the format as shown below.

```
1.Question
 1)First option  
 2)Second option  
 3)Third option
  #etc as there are more answers for some of the questions

2.  Question
 1) First option
 2) Second option
 3) Third option
 #etc as there are more answers for some of the questions
```

How do I write code to do so?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pull this off you will need to do a couple steps.

1. Read in the file

   - This can be done using the python open command https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files
   - You will either need to read the file into an array of lines or just do the next step as you are reading
2. Convert the data

   - You will need to treat the lines in groups of threes. The eaisest way to do this is to track the line number and do different things based on index % 3

     - index % 3 = 0

       - Store the question in a temporary variable
     - index % 3 = 1

       - break the line along your `._` delimiter and store the resulting array in another temporary variable (https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split)
     - index % 3 = 2

       - store the question and answers in the python tuple
3. Now that you have the tuple display it using standard output mechanisms